# Error after updating to Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift

I have recently updated XCode. Since that time I am errors.

Here is my **code**:

```
       public func asUIImage() -> UIImage? {
        if let path = value as? String{
            let docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] 
            let imageDirPath = docsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("SwiftDataImages")
            let fullPath = stringByAppendingPathComponent(path)
            if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fullPath) {
                print("SwiftData Error -> Invalid image ID provided")
                return nil
            }
            let imageAsData = NSData(contentsOfFile: fullPath)
            if let imageAsData = imageAsData {
                return UIImage(data: imageAsData)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

**Errors:**

For the variable called `let imageDirPath`:

> stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable use
>   URLByAppendingPathComponent on NSURL instead

For the variable `let fullPath`

> Use of unresolved identifier stringByAppendingPathComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringByAppendingPathComponent(str:)` is removed from `String` in Swift 2.0. It is still working for `NSString` so you can use it like this:

```
let docsPath: NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]
let imageDirPath: NSString = docsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("SwiftDataImages")
let fullPath = imageDirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(path)
```

Declare `docsPath` and `imageDirPath` as `NSString`.